# What is the correct way to center a menu?

Tags: css

I am adding a responsive navigation bar to a website, closely based on a w3 school tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp). 
All is working fine, except that I am trying to center the menu links on the page (for the desktop version), instead of having it on the left side like the tutorial explains.

I tried modifying the value of each property, including float, but without success so far. It must be extremely simple, but what am I missing?

html:

```
  <div class="nav" id="nav">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
    <a href="#drinks">Drinks</a>
    <a href="#values">Values</a>
    <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
    <a href="#booking">Booking</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.nav {
  background-color: gold;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav a {
  float: left; 
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: pink; 
  color: green;
}
.nav .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

I saw that this question has already been asked with bootstrap, but as a beginner, I am only using plain css here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach if you wanted to avoid using flexbox for whatever reason would be to set the menu items to `display: inline-block` instead of using floating. Then a simple `text-align: center` on the nav wrapper will be sufficient.

*On a side note, it would make more sense semantically to use the `<nav>` element as a wrapper and put the menu items in a `<ul>` list as `<li>` elements.*

```css
.nav {
  background-color: gold;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: pink;
  color: green;
}

.nav .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav" id="nav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
  <a href="#drinks">Drinks</a>
  <a href="#values">Values</a>
  <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
  <a href="#booking">Booking</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use flex with center layout, give it a try

```
.topnav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

Comment: thanks, my first thought was to use Flexbox, but until I learn how to fix it properly, it messes with the media query for mobiles.